# Is function $f(x,y)=x(4-y^2)$ injective / surjective? Sketch $f^{-1}[B]$, where $b = [0 ; +\infty)$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

There is a fuction $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \implies \mathbb{R} $  given by:
$$f(x,y)=x(4-y^2)$$

- Is the function injective?
- Is the function surjective?
- find and sketch $f^{-1}[B]$, where $b = [0 ; +\infty)$

Here is an sketch:
[sketch (I am not allowed to share images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMTRo.png)

As we can see, function $f$ can be described as a linear function with all it's rotations besides those that would cover the blue part of cartesian coordinate system. The function gets most vertival for $y = 0$.

Therefore, I would say that the function is injective.

However, I am not sure if it's surjective since for $y = -2$ the function is constant and returns only the value $0$.

And finally, the last part. I know that $f^{-1}[B]$, for $b = [0 ; +\infty)$ is an counterimage. The problem is, that in that case I have 2 separate types of argements. I would say that the answer is:

- {$n \in (-2 ; 0)\cup(0;2)\}\cap $ {$x \in (0; +\infty)$}
- {$n \in (-\infty ; -2)\cup(2;\infty)\}\cap $ {$x \in (-\infty;0)$}

Comment: Function is injective?? Observe that $(0,y) \mapsto 0,$ for any $y \in \Bbb R.$ Surjectivity is easy to observe. For instance fix some $y \neq \pm 2$ and vary $x.$

Comment: Ok, I am not sure about that injectivity. Is surjectivity so sure if it doesn't work for $y = +/- 2$? I think that my biggest problem is wrapping my head around an idea of y being an argument and a value at the same time.

Comment: For the last part we must have $$f^{-1} \left [B \right] = \left ( \left [0, \infty \right ) \times \left [-2, 2 \right ] \right ) \cup \left ( \left (-\infty,0 \right ) \times \left (\left (-\infty,2) \cup (2, \infty \right ) \right ) \right ).$$

Comment: Phi beta kappa is correct. For the last part, I suggest factoring $y^2 -4$ and solving for where f is nonnegative.

Comment: @functionQ if you fix $y \neq \pm 2$ then the part $(4-y^2)$ is just a non-zero constant. What can you say about the function $g : \Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by $$g(x) = cx,\ x \in \Bbb R$$ where $c$ is some non-zero real number? Isn't it surjective?

Answer (score 1):

For any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(\frac{a}{4},0)=a$. So surjective.

$f(x,2)=0$ for any $x$. So not injective.

For the image of $f^{-1}[B]$, use case analysis method:

- $|y|>2 \longrightarrow$ $x \in (-\infty,0]$
- $|y|=2 \longrightarrow$ $x$ is any real number.
- $|y|<2 \longrightarrow$ $x \in [0,\infty)$

Here is the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This function is not injective.  For all $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$, $f(x,y) = f(x,-y)$, so most points in the image have at least two preimages.  (In fact, most points have infinitely many preimages.)

This function is easily seen to be surjective.  Let $u \in \Bbb{R}$ be an arbitrary point in the codomain.  Then $f(u,\sqrt{3}) = u$.

For $f(x,y) \geq 0$: the product of two terms is nonnegative when both are nonnegative or both are nonpositive.  So,
$$  \{(x,y) \mid x \geq 0 \text{ and } 4 - y^2 \geq 0\} \\ \quad \cup \{(x,y) \mid x \leq 0 \text{ and } 4 - y^2 \leq 0\}  \text{.}  $$
Easy simplifications: \begin{align*}
& \{(x,y) \mid x \geq 0 \text{ and } 4 - y^2 \geq 0\}  \\
    &\quad {} \cup \{(x,y) \mid x \leq 0 \text{ and } 4 - y^2 \leq 0\}  \\
    &\quad {} = \{(x,y) \mid x \geq 0 \text{ and } 4 \geq y^2\}  \\
        &\qquad {} \cup \{(x,y) \mid x \leq 0 \text{ and } 4 \leq y^2\}  \\
    &\quad {} = \{(x,y) \mid x \geq 0 \text{ and } -2 \leq y \leq 2\}  \\
        &\qquad {} \cup \{(x,y) \mid x \leq 0 \text{ and } ( y \leq -2 \text{ or } 2 \leq y)\}
\end{align*}

And this is easy to plot.

[image: Mathematica graphics]